# Wants to remove markerClusterer When map is at max. zoom level when one or more markers are at same location

Tags: javascript, dictionary, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

Can anyone suggest how to remove markerClusterer when map is at max. zoom level so that markers are made visible.

also having problem in showing the markers with same latitude and longitude. When map is at max. zoom level even then marker clusterer is showing.

plz suggest something...

i was initialized markerClusterer as

```
zoom=zoom==-1?null:zoom;
size=size==-1?null:size;
style=style==-1?null:style;
markerClusterer=new MarkerClusterer(map,markers,{maxZoom:zoom,gridSize:size,styles:map_cluster_style[style]});
```

Wants to remove markerClusterer When map is at max. zoom level when one or more markers are at same location

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i resolved it my self.

by defining the value of zoom which is equal to the maxzoom of the map.

```
zoom=zoom==-1?18:zoom;
```

`size=size==-1?null:size;
style=style==-1?null:style;
markerClusterer=new MarkerClusterer(map,markers,{maxZoom:zoom,gridSize:size,styles:map_cluster_style[style]});`